# M2: Cannot add products to product collection in category list

Tags: magento2

My client requested to show 3 random products (from a known list of products) in a specific category for marketing purpose.

I tried to put an Observer using the event `catalog_product_collection_load_after` and add 3 items using:
`$collection->addItem($item);` and it worked, bringing all these products into product list.

But after that i am facing a problem with the pager.

At first i had 10 products (2 pages showing 9 products / page) and now i have 13, but instead of having 2 pages: (1st page 9/13 products and 2nd page 4/13), now the pages are: (1st page 12/10 products and 2nd page 1/10).

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this or how to implement this functionality more efficient?

Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: I don't have a way of implementing this, but I can explain why it does not work as you expect it to work.  The event `catalog_product_collection_load_after` is called (as the name suggests) after the collection is loaded. This means that the filters and pagination is already applied. So your collection that you have to display already contains only 9 products (the first page). What you add, will be added to this filtered collection and the pagination will not be applied to the new collection. So you need to find a way to attach the products to the collection before loading it.

Comment: This is exactly my thoughts Marius. That's why i tried to find where Magento applies filter to collection (eg category filter) but i couldn't find it anywhere. Do you have any idea where i can manipulate the collection before pagination is applied?

Comment: not really. I mentioned that in my previous comment.